# Google OAuth not working out the box in react-native-app-auth

Tags: react-native, google-oauth, appauth

This code is from the [google oauth example](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth/blob/master/docs/config-examples/google.md).

```
const config = {
  issuer: 'https://accounts.google.com',
  clientId: 'GOOGLE_OAUTH_APP_GUID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  redirectUrl: 'com.googleusercontent.apps.GOOGLE_OAUTH_APP_GUID:/oauth2redirect/google',
  scopes: ['openid', 'profile']
};

// Log in to get an authentication token
const authState = await authorize(config);
```

However, after signing in and being redirected to the app, I get an error:

`client_secret is missing`

[image: react-native android error]
Adding `clientSecret` to the config fixes the problem on iOS. However, on android, adding `clientSecret` does not allow me to log in with google and instead loads this error page saying that `client_secret` is not allowed.

[image: google invalid request page]

So it's a little bit of a catch-22. If I provide the clientSecret, I get an invalid request error from google and can't authenticate. If I don't provide it, I get "client_secret is missing" error after authenticating.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `SHA1 key` in the `firebase` and make sure there is support `email` present.

Comment: I am not using firebase, but I do have a support email configured for the project on console.cloud.google.com.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in the config:

clientSecret: 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY',

Comment: I tried this and discussed in the original question. That works in iOS but on android the error above is rendered: `Parameter not allowed for this message type: client_secret`